# External JavaScript file is not defined

Tags: javascript

For a web project, I've included a JavaScript file as a script src, as shown here.

```
<script src="xml2json.js"> //same directory as the web project
```

Next, I tried to invoke a method within `xml2json`, called `xml_str2json`.

```
 downloadUrl("ship_track_ajax.php", function(data) {

                  var xml_string = data.responseText; //an XML string
                  //A parser to transform XML string into a JSON object is required.
                  //Use convert XML to JSON with xml2json.js
                  var markers = xml2json.xml_str2json(xml_string);  
 }
```

However, console log indicates `"Uncaught ReferenceError: xml2json is not defined"`, even though `xml2json` is included as a script src. Can anyone tell me as to what is wrong?

Comment: Including the file won't make the functions in there have the prefix 'xml2json' - unless there is an object in that file with that name and the methods you're using.

Comment: Which library is it? This one: https://github.com/henrikingo/xml2json

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function directly in javascript without reffering the filename as like

```
xml_str2json(xml_string);
```

If the function is defined in any of the included file it will be invoked.

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Ankit. However, I tried doing that and it says that xml_str2json not defined. Within the external file, the function is defined as this.xml_str2json. Could this be an issue?

Comment: what is `this` referring to inside your javascript file ? Can you update your question for better understanding by putting JS code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
 var json = xml2json(parseXml(xml), "  ");
```

See [Demo](https://github.com/henrikingo/xml2json/blob/master/xml2json_demo.html) from https://github.com/henrikingo/xml2json